# Attempt to access index out of bounds error in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working on this code but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong
This is the part of the code that shows errors:

```
sf_num=0; sf_den=0;a=0; o=0;
for i=1:512
    for j=1:512
        sf_num=sf_num+(w1(i,j)*o(i,j));
        a=a+(o(i,j)*o(i,j));
        b=b+(w1(i,j)*w1(i,j));
        sf_den = sqrt(sf_den + a*double(b));
    end
end
```

and this is the error:

```
Attempted to access o(1,2); index out of bounds because numel(o)=1.

Error in ==> dwtcode at 44
    sf_num=sf_num+(w1(i,j)*o(i,j));
```

Comment: Because 'o' as you defined it is just a scalar...

Comment: @Jan,thanks for your response,but what should I do and how should I do to make it work

Comment: VECTORIZE THE CODE!!!!

Comment: Could you explaing a bit more? What are `o` and `w1` supposed to be? It could be possible to vectorize the code (as @Shai said)

Answer (score 2):

You define `o` as: `o=0` making it a scalar, meaning it only has 1 element.

You can't access index `1,2` of `o` because it doesn't have that many elements